# Javascript regular expression for creating HTML list

Tags: javascript, regex, html-lists

I have to create **html list** from this code

```
- ali
- hammad
- shah
-- haripur hazara
-- gaga goo
- naqvi
```

The '-' represents starting of a list and nested list elements have extra '-' symbol as you can see with 'haripur hazara' and 'gaga gogo'. There is no limit on how many nested lists one can insert. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var  h = [];
var d = 0, dl = 0;
var s = "- ali\n" +
        "- hammad\n" +
        "- shah\n" +
        "-- haripur  hazara\n" +
        "--- gaga goo\n" +
        "- naqvi ";

var a = s.split('\n'); 

for(var x=0,l=a.length;x<l;x++)
{
    d=a[x].indexOf(' ');
    if(d>dl){h.push('<ul>');}
    if(d<dl){h.push('</ul>');}
    h.push('<li>'+a[x].substring(d+1) + '</li>');
    dl=d;
}
while(d-- > 0){h.push('</ul>');}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = h.join('');
```

Comment: @Alexander - since there was no mention of regexp in the actual question, I assumed the OP just wanted to solve their problem.  If they *need* to use regexp to do this then maybe they have 2 problems...  :)